# Transparent bootstrap dropdown menu

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make a Bootstrap menu like this one https://makr.com/

I´m doing ok, but I haven't figured out how I can make it completely transparent one hover.

As you can see in the fiddle below there is always some shade of grey in the dropdown when I hover.

I really don´t know what more I can do... I've been googling and searching for a solution all yesterday and this morning and I'm really stuck now.

can anyone take a look at the fiddle and advise me, it would be very much appreciated

The only colour that should be in the menu is the

```
.navbar-default { 
  background-color: transparent; border-color: transparent;
  } 
.navbar-default :hover { 
   background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, .7); border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, .7)
{
```

on hover

https://jsfiddle.net/dadihall/5zzcq2t5/22/

thanks in advance
Dadi

Comment: set `box-shadow` to `none` like this `.dropdown-menu{box-shadow:none;}`

Comment: Already did that, as seen in the fiddle

Comment: see my answer.It works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.navbar:hover {
background: rgba(248, 248, 248, 0.7) none repeat scroll 0 0 !important;
  }
 .navbar-default *:hover{
 background:transparent !important;
 }
```

see [fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/xt55p4dp/)

Comment: I'm sorry but it's still not working, thanks for the effort though

Comment: I see it, the dropdown still has this different shade of grey, I want it to be in the exact same color as the navbar is on hover.

Comment: dont know something wrong with the `.navbar-default *`

Answer (score 0):

Hi there please try the following css

```
    .dropdown.full-width {
width : 120px;
background-image: transparent;
background-color: transparent;
}

.full-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
white-space: normal; 
 background-image: transparent;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); //or any level of transparency
} 

    .full-width.dropdown > .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5); //or any level of transparency
}
```

Comment: Hi, no it´s not working, there is still this shade of grey behind the text in the dropdown, I want it to be completely transparent. It is supposed to lay on the `.navbar-default {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default :hover {
    background-color: rgba(248, 248, 248, .7);
    border-color: rgba(231, 231, 231, .7);`  so the only color in the menu on dropdown is this .7 grey

Comment: have you tried adding background-color: transparent !important;